# Confusion about proof that every submodule of a semisimple module contains a simple module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, lattice-orders

Theorem 8.3 of [these commutative algebra notes](http://www.mat.uniroma3.it/users/fontana/documents/clarck-commutative%20algebra.pdf) by Pete L. Clark characterizes semisimple modules.

**Theorem 8.3.** For an $R$-module $M$, TFAE:

1. $M$ is a direct sum of simple submodules.
2. Every submodule of $M$ is a direct summand.
3. $M$ is a sum of simple submodules.

The proof of (2)$\implies$(1) involves a claim whose proof I do not understand. Here's the argument.
[image]

I don't understand the equality sign. In general there's a canonical *containment* $$(a\vee b)\wedge (a\vee c)\geq a\vee(b\wedge c)$$ induced by universal properties of meets and joins. (In the proof $b\wedge c=0$ so the RHS is just $a$.) Being an equality is an instance of the codistributivity axiom which as a property of a poset is equivalent to distributivity. Why is there equality here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in (D\oplus F)\cap (D\oplus G)$, $x=d+f, d\in D, f\in F, x=d'+g, d'\in D, g\in G$, it implies that $d-d'=g-f$. $d-d'\in D, g-f\in F\oplus G$, since $(F\oplus G)\cap D=0$, we deduce that $d-d'=0$ and $g-f=0$. This implies that $g=f$ since $F\cap G=0$, we deduce that $f=g=0$.

Comment: Almost the same question: there's a canonical arrow $0=(F\cap D)\oplus (G\cap D)\to (F\oplus G)\cap D$, but why is it an equality?

Comment: Because by definition $E=D\oplus F\oplus G$ this implies that $(F\oplus G)\cap D=0$.